# How do I sum row values based on serial no. & date header?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to sum the total points according to serial number and date.

**Sheet A**

```
S/N  28/9  29/9  30/9  01/10  02/10  03/10  04/10
A01                    1.0    2.0
A02  1.0   3.0                1.0    4.0
```

Whereas I would need to total up the points in sheet B.

**Sheet B**

```
S/N  September Points  October Points
A01                    3.0
A02  4.0               5.0
```

It should also only sum the points if it has passed today's date. How am I able to do this with formulas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! How do you get 4.0 for A02 in October as its points are for September?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Oops, that was a mistake from my end, I have edited the post accordingly

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have? Newest 365 version has some great functions which can help here

Comment: @MátéJuhász Version 16.42

Comment: Try to use Power Query, transform date to MONTH first and create a PivotTable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo you can adapt.  It is for a **single** S/N and **two** months.  With data in *Sheet A* like:

[image]

In *Sheet B*, cells **B2** and **C2** enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Sheet A'!B2:XFD2)*(MONTH('Sheet A'!B1:XFD1)=9))
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Sheet A'!B2:XFD2)*(MONTH('Sheet A'!B1:XFD1)=10))
```

resulting in :

[image]

Using this as a starting point, you can add as many `S/N`'s and months as you need.

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:**

*I would like to suggest a method which is an extension of @Gary's Student formula. The reason behind are, to add one more criteria and use single formula.*

*Since OP is looking to get Total value of particular months falls in two category, A01 and A02.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter `09/01/20` in cell U6 and `10/01/20` in V6.
- Apply `mmmm` cell format on both U6 & V6.
- Enter this formula in cell U7 and fill across.

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(--(SheetA!$U$2:$AA$3)*(MONTH(SheetA!$U$1:$AA$1)=MONTH(U$6)*(SheetA!$T$2:$T$3=$T7)))
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 365 you can do it easily with [`FILTER`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) function:

`=SUM(FILTER($B2:$H2,MONTH($B$1:$H$1)=B$6))`

[image]

Need to pay attention to absolute and relative references.